# How to print top words from wordcloud

Tags: python, word-cloud

I have a word cloud generated using the wordcloud library. I got an image of the wordcloud. Now I want a list of the top x words of the wordcloud. How do I do that? I don't want the most frequent words. I want the most frequent and most important words which is what the image shows.

Here is the wordcloud library: [link](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html)

Comment: most. important is most frequent right? else define most important

Comment: Is this a image-recognition/OCR question? If not, can your word-cloud library not give you the words more directly?

Comment: @bigbounty By most important, I mean whatever the wordcloud generator thinks is most important. I've added a link to the library I'm referring to. I simply want the "large" printed words without having to manually look at what words are in the largest font.

Comment: @mkoistinen That's what I want to know. I've added a link to the library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```py
print(wordcloud.words_.keys())
```